# Firebase back-up

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase for an Android project and I have some data into a database. I want to know if there is any possibility to save/make a back up to the structure of data. I ask this because somehow, I deleted the project and I had to do all again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just deleted your project, you *may* still be able to restore it from the [<kbd>Resources pending deletion</kbd> page in the Google Cloud Platform console](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager?pendingDeletion=true) with the [process shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwtw6fSARek).

If that doesn't work, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to see if they can help you recover it.

Note that both of these are dependent on the time that has passed since you deleted the project, so time is of the essence.